# Entity framework get set property is not assigned

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nopcommerce

I was working on Ecommerce (Nopcommerce) system with multiple store model. I am using Entity frawork for class to db mapping. Each customer can browse only his assigned store.

```
private Store _customerStore;



 public virtual Store Store
        {
            get { return _customerStore ?? (_customerStore = new List<Store>().Where(s => s.Id == this.StoreId).FirstOrDefault()); }
            protected set { _customerStore = value; }
        }   

   public virtual int StoreId { get; set; }
```

Last one is foreign key for relation between store and customer

But the store for the customer is getting null.

Any Help.

Comment: Well that's because you are querying what looks like an empty list...

Comment: No query shall be present within a property. This breaks both SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) and LSP (Liskov Substitution Principle).

Comment: @WillMarcouiller by that logic, navigation properties shouldn't be used and they are, pretty heavily.

Comment: Thanks all. So should i assing directly store to customer while inserting in db like Customer.Store=_storeService.GetStoreById(id)?

Comment: What you effectively have here is a navigation property, and that's something you get for free with Entity Framework (assuming your DB is setup correctly).

Comment: @James Couldnt get u, what way should i prefer can u post ur answer with some sample code

Comment: @NitinVarpe are you using [Code First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj193542.aspx)?

Comment: @James yes I am using Code First

Comment: @James: The underlying datasource "knows" the relationship between Customer and Store. In OOP, the Customer simply shall have a Store instance as a property, and this has to be either lazy-loaded or eager-loaded while getting the Customer from the datasource through the Repository.

Comment: @James thanks for ur suggestions will try to work on it

Comment: Well, which version of nopcommerce you are using? i am working with nop 3.20. There is not out of the box mapping of a customer with particular store. Because, there is no store id in the customer table.

Comment: @Jeyara working with 2.40 version. There isnt multiple store model, but we have customized it for having mutliple stores